# Sending data from arduino to phone using HC05

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

How can i send real time data from a thermometer to my arduino and then recieve that data on my phone using bluetooth HC05

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to
[Arduino Bluetooth Basic Tutorial](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/user206876468/arduino-bluetooth-basic-tutorial-d8b737)